# Create a program that prompt user fa a floating point(double) Fahrenheit and then return equal value in Celsius

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;  

class TempConver {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        double temperature;  
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.printf("Enter Fahrenheit Temperature: ");  
        temperature = in.nextInt();  

        temperature = (temperature - 32) * 5 / 9;  
        System.out.printf("Censius Temperatre is  = " + temperature);   
   }
}
```

I've to write program using information given below.

- output formatting - "printf()" instead of print() or println()
- Do While loops - repeat a question until a user gives you a valid response
- Scanner.HasNextDouble() - method to ascertain whether or not the next item the scanner is about to read works as a double data type

Please help  me how to write output in 2 place decimal using do while loop. !!

Comment: Two things:  be sure that you're dividing/multiplying by a double, and I'm unclear as to what it is you're actually...asking for...

Comment: This isn't exactly a homework solution site.  This will probably be flagged as such.  To try and avoid it you might want to update your question with things you have tried or at least some sketches on a napkin type thing.  Do you have any ideas how you would like to solve this?

Comment: What is the question? is it the last line, about 2 decimal place formatted output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the answers you need in the hints.

**Do While loops - repeat a question until a user gives you a valid response And `Scanner.hasNextDouble()` - method to ascertain whether or not the next item the scanner is about to read works as a double data type**

Here you are telling the user, while the input is not a double, then execute the code. Which will be asking the user for input until you get a double

```
while (!in.hasNextDouble()) {
    // code here
}
```

To round to two decimals you can use `Math.round()` to round a value to the nearest integer, and multiply temperature by 100 then divide by 100.

```
int round = (int) Math.round(temperature*100);
temperature = round / 100.0;
```

Full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    double temperature;  
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
    System.out.printf("Enter Fahrenheit Temperature: "); 

    // As long as it is not a double ask for another input
    while (!in.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.printf("Please enter a valid number:");
        in.next(); 
    }
    temperature = in.nextDouble();
    temperature = (temperature - 32) * 5 / 9;  

    // Use only 2 decimals
    int round = (int) Math.round(temperature*100);
    temperature = round / 100.0;

    System.out.printf("Censius Temperatre is  = " + temperature);  
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Victor !! Your are awesome :) and yes it help me lot.